# register bower packages in nexus oss

Tags: bower, nexus

I have configured bower and nexus using this tut:

> https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bower.html

I have `bowerrc.json` like below:

`{
"registry" : {
"search" : [
"http://localhost:8081/repository/bower-all/"
],
"register" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/bower-internal"
},
"resolvers" : [ "bower-nexus3-resolver" ]
}`

and i use `bower-nexus3-resolver` as resolver integrating bower and nexus.
this config installs bower packages and packages are cached in nexus but i cant register my own bower package locally in nexus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering your own packages is documented [here](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bower.html#bower-register). Following the steps there should work just fine. Keep in mind that bower registries point back to a git server typically so you have to have that running as well.

Comment: it's ok, i'd forgotten to specify the credentials for the accessing the repository manager,i add this to bowerrc.json: http://admin:admin123@localhost:8081/repository/bower-all/